# Move an entire TD in a responsive design?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a webpage that I am transforming into a responsive page. I have a traditional table with TR's and TD's. Is there a way to move the contents for a TD when a certain width is reached? See code below (can't post a picture yet) - I want D (a button) to move besides A for each table row for some widths.

`<tr>
  <td>A<td>B<td>C<td>D`

should become:

`<tr>
  <td>AD<td>B<td>C`

I hope you understand a bit what I am looking for. Is the best way to have it hidden there at all times and make it visible when reaching the width? Or does that make the site slow?

Comment: You can't change a table structure with CSS. Best would be not to use tables for layout in the first place. Try posting some design sketches  that show the layout you want in different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried having a `<td>` with CSS styling on it as `display:inline-block; width:20% min-width:100px;` - This will set the width of the `td` to 20% of the `tr` until it becomes 100px wide, anything smaller than that will give the `tr`it will display as a block element on its own row

changing:
 A | B | C | D

to

A

B

C

D

Your question is worded weirdly however, so if I misunderstood the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to hide/show the contents rather than try to move them. So put at the screenwidth you dont want the last cell to be visible.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A<span class="showMobile">D</span></td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td class="hideMobile">D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.showMobile{
    display:block;
}
.hideMobile{
    display:none;
}

@media (min-width:500px){
    .showMobile{
        display:none;
    }
    .hideMobile{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pxt6xnfc/)**

Further to your question regarding speed. Hide/show based on media queries should be a heck of a lot faster than moving/removing/readding DOM elements using JS.

PS. be careful of your DOM markup, you have tags not being closed which can get messy.